# Is there a way to visualize how a fragment would look like when it's loaded in android studio inspector?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, fragment

I'm making an android app that has a couple of fragments in it. I was wondering if you could look at how your fragments would look like when they are loaded in the layout inspector. It would be much more easy to adjust them as now I have to deploy the app to my phone every time I want to look at what has changed. I can't use the emulator because I'm using frameworks that don't run on the emulator.

[image: screenshot]

It would be nice if instead of them showing as `<fragment>` I could see what they would look like in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`tools:layout="@android:layout/myfragment"`

Don't forget to add tools namespace to root element : `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Comment: Thanks it worked, though for my case it was `tools:layout="@layout/myfragment"`